# Gridview used to display list data does not show 'Author' and 'Editor' field

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, list

I used grid view to display SharePoint 2010 list data. To have data filtered (used Sp-query for that), I used 'Author' field in C# which is similar to 'Created By' in SharePoint list. It's working fine in the local development. But when deploy the code in test environment, it was throwing error:

> Field not found: Author

```
Sp Query is queryRR.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='User'>" + userName + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Publish' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq></And></Where>"
```

Then I changed the code and put all the list data in grid (without any condition). Again deployed the code in test and checked it, I found both columns were missing - Author (Created By) and Editor (Modified By). It was strange. I checked many blogs but no use.

Is there any configuration problem on the test server or something missing in the code?

Comment: It is resoled.
The problem was different. I used View, Add & Edit permission on the list for the end user. Note here I did not use view application pages permission level, it means user is able to add/edit item (by custom application) in the list but cannot see (access denied) the list. To test the root cause, I give Full permission to one of the user and checked the list. List was giving error - 'This view cannot be displayed because the number of lookup and workflow status columns it contains exceeds the threshold (8) enforced by the administrator.’

Comment: This was the cause as I used 7-8 workflows and some views in the list. I changed it through Central Admin -> Resource Throttling. It worked with the view, add & edit permission.

Comment: You should add an answer

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you want to add viewfields

e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfields.aspx

for the test case causing an exception, perhaps check the internal name of the created by field and that all items contain a valid value

Comment: I used viewfileds also but was the same error. I resolved it. Check my comments just below the question.